# Check that a string equals "X.X", where X is a 0-9 digit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, yup

I am trying to verify that a string corresponds to this format "x.x" with x, a digit belonging to [0-9].

Right now, what I am doing is:

- checking that the string is at least, and at most, made of 3 characters
- checking that the string matches the regex [0-9.] (only digits and a dot)

So right now, I have:

```
      myString: Yup.string()
        .min(3, "Minimum 3 caractères: XXX.")
        .max(3, "Maximum 3 caractères: XXX.")
        .matches(/^[0-9]+$/, 'Doit contenir seulement des caractères numériques.')
        .nullable(),
```

Is there a way for me to:

- check that myString[0] and myString[2] are digits
- check that myString[1] is a dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just using the `matches` and pass a regex that validates the list of requirements in one go?

```
const number = string().matches(/\d{3,}\.\d{3,}/).nullable();

number.validateSync("123.456") // pass
number.validateSync("12.456") // fail min
number.validateSync("123456") // fail no dot
number.validateSync("1236.4566") // pass
```

Here `\d{3,}` matches a number with min 3 digits long followed by a dot `\.` followed by another `\d{3,}`.

Comment: Wow that worked ! I'm fairly new to regex and I didn't realised it was that powerful :o 

Thank you ! :D

Comment: Sure I used this tool https://regex101.com/ it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve your code just using regex, like in your case:

```
yup.string()
  .matches('^\d{1}\.\d{1}$', 'Doit contenir seulement des caractères numériques.')
  .nullable()
```

`\d` validates whether first and last characters are digits with second character being a `.`

Since you only need one number its `d{1}` before and after the dot.

Edit:

As @bobble bubble mentioned and after testing `d{1}` is actually redundant. In your case, the regex pattern is `^\d\.\d$`. You can use the above pattern if you want to increase the digit count.

Comment: The `dot` needs to be escaped here since this string would match `1a2` which is invalid. Make sure you add some unit tests.

Comment: `{1}` afaik is always redundant and can be dropped in a regex pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `/^[0-9][.][0-9]$/`, which I think is easier to read. Here is an example with tests:

```js
const regex= /^[0-9][.][0-9]$/;

console.log(regex.test("4.3")); // true
console.log(regex.test("9.0")); // true

console.log(regex.test("91.0")); // false
console.log(regex.test("4e3")); // false
console.log(regex.test("abc")); // false
```

With Yup, in your case, it would be:

```js
Yup.string()
  .matches(
    /^[0-9][.][0-9]$/,
    'It should be in the form of Digit + Period + Digit'
  )
  .nullable();
```

Also, you can copy past the RegEx in [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) to get an explanation of each part of it.